# Converting SQL into DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Can anyone help in converting this SQL query into DAX:

SELECT ROUND(CAST(SUM(ctScanAbort) as float) /747683, 3) FROM [PetData].[dbo].[MachineKPI]
WHERE fk_machine IN (Select m.id from [PetData].[dbo].Machine m INNER JOIN Country c ON m.fk_country = c.id WHERE m.active = 1 and c.reporting = 1 and fk_platform = 4)
AND ctScanAbort IS NOT NULL;

I tried this out:

FilteredMachineIDs =
FILTER (
'Machine',
'Machine'[active] = 1
&& 'Machine'[fk_platform] = 4
&& RELATED ( 'Country'[reporting] ) = 1
)
VAR TotalCtScanAbort =
CALCULATE (
SUM ( 'FSMachineKPI'[ctScanAbort] ),
'FSMachineKPI'[ctScanAbort] IS NOT BLANK (),
'FSMachineKPI'[fk_machine] IN VALUES ( FilteredMachineIDs[id] )
)
RETURN
ROUND ( DIVIDE ( TotalCtScanAbort, 747683 ), 3 )

Answer (score 0):

Here is the required DAX query:

```
FilteredMachineIDs = FILTER (
    'Machine',
    'Machine'[active] = 1 &&
    'Machine'[fk_platform] = 4 &&
    RELATED ( 'Country'[reporting] ) = 1
)
TotalCtScanAbort =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'MachineKPI'[ctScanAbort] ),
        'MachineKPI'[ctScanAbort] IS NOT BLANK (),
        'MachineKPI'[fk_machine] IN VALUES ( 'Machine'[id] )
    )
Result =
    ROUND ( DIVIDE ( TotalCtScanAbort, 747683 ), 3 )
```

Make sure to replace the table and column names with the appropriate ones from your data model.